# PHP: How can i convert an index to an string?

Tags: php, string, indexing

how can i convert an index to an string ?

For example i would like to get the 'signin' index here:

```
array(1) {
  ["signin"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["email_address"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["password"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Javi

Comment: Does this need to be for "indexes" meaning offset/position: i.e., "tell me the key for the nth array item"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
reset($array); // resets the internal pointer to the first element, 
               // might not be necessary
$current_key = key($array);
// $current_key = 'singin';
```

Use [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all keys of an array, e.g.:

```
$keys = array_keys('foo'=>1, 'bar'=>2);
// $keys[0] = 'foo'
// $keys[1] = 'bar'
```

To make sure that the key is a string you can use [`strval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) (in case you also have numerical indecies).

Answer (score 0):

......

```
$signin = $your_array["signin"];
```

To get the key, you can use the `key`

```
$key = key($your_array);
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

The `$signin` itself is an array, you can check out:

```
print_r($signin);
```

So you can also get email address and password like this if you want:

```
$email = $your_array["signin"]["email_address"];
$password = $your_array["signin"]["password"];
```

Comment: -1. You cannot use numeric indexes to access cells with string keys.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes you are right, forgot to do that. Fixed anyways.